# How to extract a parameter of JSON object that is full with escape characters - '\'

Tags: node.js, json

I have a serverless project running on Node JS that gets a respons to it with the following escape character - "\". Here is my object that I get as a response to me -

```
"{\"desc\":\"India next talent\",\"name\":\"אחלה ברווז\",\"uid\":\"-LnQwxh_QoYl4Qj_9M4B\"}"
```

So basiclly, as you can see, this is a JSON object with some wierd escape characters. The full object is called

```
reqBody.context.custom.miniContest
```

So what I need is the 'uid' parameters of the miniContest, but when trying to call it -

```
reqBody.context.custom.miniContest.uid
```

I get undefined. So my question is how can I extract the value of 'uid' successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're doing `JSON.stringify()` twice. You can avoid it if you've                                                the access on the server side codebase.

Say, If you have this,

```
const config = {a: 1, b: 2}
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(config)))
```

then it will produce below response with extra `\`,

```
"{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}"
```

**To extract the value of 'uid' successfully**, You can use `JSON.parse()` to make it object before accessing it, Let's do it this way-

```js
let json = "{\"desc\":\"India next talent\",\"name\":\"אחלה ברווז\",\"uid\":\"-LnQwxh_QoYl4Qj_9M4B\"}";

let result = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(result.uid);
```

Comment: @AlonShlider glad it helps you somehow, best of luck :)